# windows application development: a nebie's dilemna!EXE and installed version of .exe?

Tags: c, winapi, installation

WINDOWS: What is the difference between (.exe)file and installed .exe application?

Generally an c/c++ IDE will give you FILENAME.EXE (PE format) application output (console, GUI both) ; the output will run when clicked but IT DOES NOT enjoy facilities like an installed software packages! what difference it makes?

How can I convert my binary PE-format .exe file to standard installable software package with full professional touch? Please provide option which are free of cost?

Comment: [UPX](http://upx.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Utilities that help you create an installer for your app are plentiful.  You'll need to go shopping, utility recommendations are not on topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference between an .exe file and an "installed exe application", except that one was copied into it's place by an installer.

The installer usually allows the user to choose where the application (.exe) gets installed, creates any necessary shortcuts and registration entries, the Start menu entries, and so forth. The executable (.exe) is still the same.

All of the above can be done manually as well. The installer simply bundles them up and automates the process to make it easier for the user, and to ensure that everything gets done properly.

There are dozens of installation creation packages out there (including the one that is included in Visual Studio itself when you create a deployment package). A popular free one, if you don't need an MSI based installation, is [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php). It's free, allows you to customize your installation very easily, and pretty widely used.

If you must have an MSI installer, [WIX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) is a popular choice, although it's much more difficult to learn and use than Inno Setup is.

There are many other available installers, both free and commercial. For more information about other possibilities, search here for "windows installers" or try searching Google or Bing for the same thing.

Comment: so the difference is in only registry entry,all the shortcuts and enviornmental variable entry for path? Any more process involved? even if manually!

Comment: That depends entirely on your application; there's no generic answer to that question. If your application needs a database, for instance, that would also have to be installed or configured. It's your task as the developer to know what your application's requirements are, and then you know what's involved in installing or configuring it.

Comment: so for that one need to learn scripting properly right?either in INNO  or wix respectvely?

Comment: Once again, that depends on the specific needs of your application. There are free Inno Setup GUI tools that allow you to build some pretty complex installations with zero scripting involved, and there are other installations that are complex enough that hundreds of lines of scripting are needed. You really need to do some research, instead of just asking more and more questions in the comments here. Inno Setup has pretty good documentation and some really good sample installations that should help you get started. I don't know WIX well enough to say much, other than it seems more complicated.